# How to send token correctly?

Tags: angular, jwt

I try to set up authentication in my app. When I login I receive the token from my backend. I've an interceptor used to add token to request header. But when I logged in I redirect then I request for user list but I receive error: no token provided. When I reload the page user list is received. I don't know why

auth.service

```js
export class AuthenticationService {
        private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
        public currentUser: Observable<User>;
        public currentToken: BehaviorSubject<string>;

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
                this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
                this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
                this.currentToken = new BehaviorSubject<string>(localStorage.getItem('currentToken'));
        }

        public get currentTokenValue() {
                return this.currentToken.value;
        }

        public get currentUserValue(): User {
                return this.currentUserSubject.value;
        }

        login(loguser: User) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/authenticate`,
                loguser , { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')})

                        .pipe(map(user => {
                                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between p
                                //console.log('voilavoila :'+user.user[0]);
                                //user.token = user.token;
                                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user.user[0]));
                                localStorage.setItem('currentToken',user.token);
                                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                                console.log('localsss'+localStorage.getItem('currentToken'), ' ', localStorage.getIte
                                //      console.log('testuserrole : '+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
                                return user;
                }));
        }
        logout() {
                // remove user from local storage to log user out
                localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
                localStorage.removeItem('currentToken');
                this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
        }
}
```

interceptor

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
                // add authorization header with jwt token if available
                let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
                let currentToken = this.authenticationService.currentTokenValue;
                if (currentUser && currentToken) {
                console.log(currentToken);
                        request  = request.clone({
                                setHeaders: {
                                        Authorization: `Bearer ${currentToken}`
                                }
                        });
                }
                return next.handle(request);

        }
}
```

In the callback of my auth request I just navigate to the home page

home.component

```js
export class HomeComponent {
        loading = false;
        users: User[];

        constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

        ngOnInit() {
                this.loading = true;
                this.userService.getAll().pipe(first()).subscribe(users => {

                        console.log('récupération des users');
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.users = users;
                });
        }
}
```

It's like the interceptor doesn't intercept directly the request on user list. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you navigate the user to home after auth? I don't see it in the code

Comment: Yes navigation is done after calling login method in login.component :
```
 this.authenticationService.login(this.user)
                        .pipe(first())
                        .subscribe(
                                data => {
                                        console.log (' test '+ this.returnUrl);

                                        this.router.navigate(['/alvin/home']);
                                },
                               );```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working exactly like it should... so what happens?

App starts when user is not logged in:

```
this.currentToken = new BehaviorSubject<string>(localStorage.getItem('currentToken'));
```

Okay, so we have no value in `currentToken`, as there is no user. So next, you log in and do:

```
localStorage.setItem('currentToken',user.token);
```

User gets redirected to whatever page you redirect the user, where it fires an http-request which requires the token, but what does the interceptor get? It gets the `currentToken.value` which has no value, since you have not called `next` on the behaviorsubject, so the original `undefined` value is still there.

Anyways calling `value` of a behaviorsubject isn't really what I would recommend anyway, In my opinion it kinda works against the purpose of immutable observables.

All in all, you should handle the fetching of token in the interceptor itself, or then call `next` on the behaviorsubject after logging in. I would do the first option.

Comment: Hey thank your for your suggestion. It's seems to work using next method. I would you handle the fetching directly in the interceptor ?

Comment: add to your service `this.currentToken$ = this.currentToken.asObservable()`, then in interceptor first then call `this.authenticationService.currentToken$.pipe(take(1), switchMap(token => { return request.clone ........... }))`

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the user list is received on refresh I'm guessing that your `AuthenticationService` has not been loaded yet by the time your App makes the request for the user list (the first time). So here is what I would suggest to combat this problem if that is the case.

Change your `app.module.ts` to load your authorization service upon initialization like so:

```
  declarations: [
    .
    .
    .

  ],
  imports: [
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthenticationService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (as: AuthService) =>
        function() {
          return as.load();
        },
      deps: [AuthenticationService],
      multi: true
    },
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Then you need to change your authorization service to load your tokens inside the `load` method you will create. Like so

```
export class AuthenticationService {
        private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
        public currentUser: Observable<User>;
        public currentToken: BehaviorSubject<string>;

        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
            //move everythign that was here to the load function
        }

        load(){
            this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
            this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
            this.currentToken = new BehaviorSubject<string>(localStorage.getItem('currentToken'));
        }
```

this way you can be confident that you have loaded your tokens to the authorization service before making any requests.